# Microsoft cognitive services example in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to make work this very simple example of the Microsoft Cognitive Services in JavaScript but it's not working. I don't know why. Can some one help me or provide a working example?

I've tried to make the code work both in node and browser (of course with the right modifications to the code).

I'm getting this error in node:

> "statusCode":404,"message":"Resource not found".

While if I run the code example [provided on the website][1] I get this error:

> Access Denied (401): Access denied due to invalid subscription key

(which is weird cause I'm copying the precise key that has been provide to my in my account page).

```
const cognitiveServices = require('cognitive-services');

const computerVision = cognitiveServices.computerVision({
        API_KEY: "myAPIkey"
});
const parameters = {
    "language": "unk",
    "detectOrientation": "true",
    "content-type": "application/json"
};
const body = {
    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Space_Needle_2011-07-04.jpg"
};

computerVision.ocr({
        parameters,
        body
})
.then((response) => {
        console.log('Got response', response);
})
.catch((err) => {
        console.error('Encountered error making request:', err);
});
```

Comment: Have you signed up your Azure account to use the cognitive APIs?

Comment: @volatilevar I have created the API key following the guide in this link: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtosubscribe). Now I have 2 API keys provided in this page: [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/).

Comment: Could you please try removing line "content-type": "application/json" in your parameters?

Comment: @volatilevar I've removed it but I still get the error: **{"statusCode":404,"message":"Resource not found"}**

Comment: Could you please also remove the quotes around "language" and "detectOrientation" to make it: const parameters = {
    language: "unk",
    detectOrientation: "true"}. Also the quotes around "url"

Comment: @volatilevar I've tried but nothing, same error :-/

Comment: I see here are some discussions related to this issue. https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/issues/2 Sorry that I could not help you test the code at the moment.

Comment: If you want to use computer vision API, try this node [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-computer-vision)

Comment: @volatilevar please try with version 0.2.0, this has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please download version [0.2.0](https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/tree/v0.2.0) and it should work.